# Select bubble rating inside svg tag in selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium, svg

Hi I need some help with getting the bubble rating of this website: https://all.accor.com/hotel/1159/index.nl.shtml

```
svg class="lazysvg-loaded" data-url="/fact-sheet/assets/icons/graphics/icons.htm" 
aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">  use xlink:href="#icon-gss-rating-45"></use></svg*
```

I tried multiple things:

```
rating = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//svg[contains(@class, 'lazysvg-loaded')]").get_attribute("class").split("_")[3]
```

```
rating = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//svg[contains(@class, 'icon-gss-rating-')]").get_attribute("class").split("_")[3]
```

```
rating = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//svg[contains(@href, 'icon-gss-rating-')]").get_attribute("class").split("_")[3]
```

But I get this error everytime:

> **NoSuchElementException:** `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//svg[contains(@class, 'icon-gss-rating-')]"}`

Can anyone tell me how this needs to be done?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly is bubble rating ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
//div[@id="alert-container"]//*[name()="svg"]
```

I tested on your page.

[image]